# Get a count on an exact match from a text field in mysql

Tags: mysql, string, search, text

I have a MySql table with a text field.

The text field would be populated with a random sequence similar to this (could be any integer values though):

14,4,24,20,34,2

34,67,4,98,64

No leading or trailing comma on the string (text field value).

I would like to do a count on total occurrences of only '4' for example.

Query on these two rows should return a count of 2 and not 7.

Not positive how a query like this would be formulated.

thanks

Comment: Do you need to take account of duplicate values within a set, such as `3,4,5,4,6` or should the values within the CSV be unique? You can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) - `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM poll_info WHERE FIND_IN_SET(4, poll_blocks);`

Comment: Would it be possible to normalise the data structure and use a count() with a where clause? None of the possible solutions will be high performant ones, so using a relational data structure would speed things up considerably!

Answer (score 0):

## For MySQL 8.X

You can make use of `REGEXP_REPLACE` to find the 4, remove them from the string and compute the difference of length:

```sql
SELECT
    LENGTH(vals) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(vals, '(?<=^|,)4(?=$|,)', ''))
FROM
    T;
```

That returns the number of "4" per row, then you can sum it all up:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(LENGTH(vals) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(vals, '(?<=^|,)4(?=$|,)', '')))
FROM
    T;
```

You might also want to rename these values with `AS`.

### Explanation of the Regex

`(?<=^|,)4(?=$|,)` is looking for "4" which match these conditions:

- There's a comma or the beginning of the string before
- There's a comma or the end of the string after

## For older MySQL versions

The query is quite ugly, but you can use the following:

```sql
SELECT
    vals,
    LENGTH(Replace(Replace(Concat(',', vals, ','), ',4,', ',_,'), ',4,', ',_,')) - LENGTH(Replace(Replace(Replace(Concat(',', vals, ','), ',4,', ',_,'), ',4,', ',_,'), "_", "")) AS NB4
FROM
    test_table;
```

What it does is first replace all the occurrences of "4" as an element (so not in 54 for example) with underscores (`_`).
Then, it computes the length of the string with these underscores minus the length of the string without the underscores, and that's the number of "4"s in your list.

### Why so many `REPLACE`?

During testing the query, I've discovered that MySQL `REPLACE` functions doesn't behave as we would expect. With this example: `4,4,4,4,4`, if using a single Replace, we would expect it to return `_,_,_,_,_`. However, it does the replace in-place, and if a comma is "matched" twice, it won't count the second time, hence why 2 `REPLACE(..., ",4,", ",_,")`.

Comment: I was trying this as an example, but not getting any results (count is zero):   select count(*) as total_blocks from poll_info where poll_blocks like '4,' OR poll_blocks like ',4,' OR poll_blocks like ',4'

Comment: Testing I am gettng an error of "REGEXP_REPLACE does not exist"

Comment: SELECT SUM(LENGTH(poll_blocks) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(poll_blocks, '(?<=^|,)4(?=$|,)', ''))) FROM poll_info

Comment: @Peter what's your mysql version? edit: ah yeah, only works with mysql 8.X

Comment: Not positive, but I doubt it is ver 8, hence the error, can REGEXP_LIKE be used instead?

Comment: REGEXP_* functions are for versions 8.X only

Comment: @Peter updated my answer with a solution for mysql 5.7 (and basically any version prior to mysql 8)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got working, and seems to give the correct result:

`select count(*) as total_blocks from poll_info where poll_blocks like '%,4,%' OR poll_blocks like '4,%' OR poll_blocks like '%,4'`

I will do some further testing and hopefully this will solve the issue, thanks for your time in this.

Comment: This will only return the amount of rows with at least one 4 in it, but try it with these rows: `54,23,4,3,4`, `4,4,4,4`, `3,3,4,4,3`, etc